# Entity Framework Relation with null or 0 Key

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-fluent-api

I am trying to work with an existing database and my ability to make changes are difficult. I am hoping to do some transitional work and being an ORM in however, i have hit an issue.

I am using EF Fluent API (closer to the NHibernate way of doing things) and we have a nullable column `ParentId` in the database. I have created a `HasOptional` relationship for this and it works:

```
HasOptional(x => x.Parent).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("ParentId"));
```

This particular column seems to have a lot of 0's in this column (they don't use foreign keys) and I may not be able to add a FK constraint as that my break their other applications (as I would need to go though and alter / delete everything that doesn't have a FK match). EF does handle this well enough and for these records that don't have a matching parent for id 0, EF gets null. This however falls over if I try to use a Linq query like this:

```
myitems.Where(i => Parent != null)
```

to select everything where `Parent != null`. This translates this type of SQL query

```
WHERE ParentId = null
```

This of course does not get the desired results as it returns the records that have a `ParentId` of `0`. When I inspect the object, as expected based on this SQL query, I get results that both have parent correctly and many that have parent as null.

Is there a way to get EF to translate this column in its queries to something like `NULLIF(0)`? If not, I need some ideas on how I can work around this so I can use EF without having to cause breaking changes in the database.

I have already considered a computed column, but that would only help me on the querying. It will fall over if I ever try to persist the entity.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround i have just realised is by modifying my query to something like this:

```
myitems.Where(i => i.Parent != null && i.Parent.Id != 0)
```

This does get around it, but it does mean my queries will always need to take into account this issue with the database, where i was hoping that all of this could be handled seamlessly by the mapping. Still hoping for a better answer than this.